# Maneira correta de utilizar dois contextos em asp.net core com entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Estou tentando aplicar o que venho estudando e travei em uma parte de contextos.

O que estou tentando aplicar é utilizar a estrutura do Microsoft *Identity* com as minhas entidades da aplicação.

Estrutura da ***solution***:

```
- BaseFull.Web
- BaseFull.Entities
- BaseFull.Infra.Data
```

Criei uma interface para manter as mesmas novas propriedades e assim não ter problema de '*migration*' de duas classes para a mesma 'tabela'.

```
    public interface IUsuario
    {
        string Fullname { get; set; }
    }
```

Apliquei na minha entidade Usuario e na ApplicationUser:

```
namespace BaseFull.Web.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser,  IUsuario
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace BaseFull.Entities.Models
{
    public class Usuario : IUsuario
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public Usuario()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        #region Propriedades da AspnetUsers(Identity)
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }


  ...
        #endregion
    }
```

Como notaram, separei as entidades em um projeto. Estou tentando também separar o contexto em um projeto e é ai que travei.

```
        namespace BaseFull.Infra.Data.Context
    {
        public class BaseFullContext: DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
....

namespace BaseFull.Web.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Usuarios");
```

Na classe Startup do projeto Web fiz a chamada dos contextos:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<BaseFullContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));....
```

Apresentou o erro de assembly, que pesquisando resolvi alterando o serviço para a mesma assembly do projeto principal.

```
services.AddDbContext<BaseFullAppContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                                , b => b.MigrationsAssembly("BaseFull.Web"))
```

Porém ao executar o update do segundo contexto gerou o erro da tabela já existir.

```
 There is already an object named 'Usuarios' in the database.
```

Minha maior dúvida é como resolver este problema, qual a maneira mais correta e a melhor para utilizar os dois contextos para isso.

A classe de configuração do Usuario para se manter igual a ApplicationUser não mostrei aqui pois não acho que seja necessário, mas se precisar eu mostro também.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais correta depende do tipo de aplicação que você esta desenvolvendo. Sempre existira trade-off. Sobre seu erro, é por que essa tabela ja esta definida no context do Idendity. Você pode ter uma outra tabela de usuário que tem como referencia o Id do usuário do Identity. Ou usar o mesmo DbContext do Identity para fazer seu aplicação.